# How to remove time from date in yajra datatable

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am using Laravel yajra datatable and I want to show only date in column , but unfortunately I am also getting time please help me how can I show date ?

[image]

start date and and date should be like that in date column.

```
2022-04-17 - 2022-04-23
```

**BookingController**

```
  public function datatables()
    {

        $booking = Booking::select(['id','start_datetime','end_datetime'])->get();

        return Datatables::of($booking)
        ->addColumn('mergeColumn', function($row){
        return $row->start_datetime.' - '.$row->end_datetime;
        })
        ->make(true);
    }
```

**Jquery Script**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('datatables.data') }}",
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "mergeColumn",
                "defaultContent": ""
            },

        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": 'no-sort',
                "orderable": false,
            },
              {
            "targets": 0,
            "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return  data;
            },
        },

        ],
        "drawCallback": function (settings) {
      },
        //scrollX:true,
    });

    });
```

Comment: You mean you want to replace `$row->start_datetime` and `$row->end_datetime` with just the date?

Comment: actually i want to show date and time separately , start date and end date should be in date column and start time and end time should be  shown in time slot thank u.

Comment: What I really meant was that when you ask questions you should focus on where the problem is. You have a thing in PHP with the value `2022-04-17 12:00:00` and you want to get the value `"2022-04-17"`. But you also posted a lot of not-very-relevant stuff about jquery, and it wasn't immediately obvious which part I was supposed to be looking at. So it's better to narrow it down if you can. (Having said that, some of the more weird bugs turn out to come from somewhere unexpected, so there are times when it's better to say all the things.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Carbon library in Laravel to parse your datetime strings and format them in any way you like. The controller code would look something something like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

// ...

public function datatables()
{
    $booking = Booking::select(['id','start_datetime','end_datetime'])
        ->get()
        ->map(function($booking) {
            $start = Carbon::parse($booking->start_datetime);
            $end = Carbon::parse($booking->end_datetime);
            return [
                'id' => $booking->id,
                'start_date' => $start->format('Y-m-d'),
                'end_date' => $end->format('Y-m-d'),
            ];
        });

    return Datatables::of($booking)
        ->addColumn('mergeColumn', function($row){
            return $row['start_date'] . ' - ' . $row['end_date'];
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

You can get the time values from the `$start` and `$end` variables too if you need them.